# $B^{2}=0$ if and only if $B$ and the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ are similar

Tags: matrices

Suppose that $B$ is a nonzero matrix in $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$. Prove that $B^{2}=0$ if and only if $B$ and the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ are similar

I've done one way which is fairly obvious by definition. That is if the matrices are similar, then $B^{2}=0$. Having trouble proving the inverse.

Comment: Can you use the Jordan normal form for matrices over $\mathbb{C}$? Even if you can't, it gives you the hint to look at characteristic and minimal polynomials of matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $B^2=0$. Note that the rank of $B$ is $1$. Choose $w$ such that $Bw\ne0$. Prove that $\{w,Bw\}$ is a basis.

What is the matrix of $v\mapsto Bv$ with respect to this basis?